# SpEL @Value with nested condition

Tags: java, spring, spring-el

I'm using the `@Value` annotation, and I want it to be a bit more complex now. I have two config values - `val1`, and `val2`. I want to inject it as follows: If `val1` exists in the configuration, use it. Else, if `val2` is true, inject `default1`. If it's false, inject `default2`.

I tried something like:

`@Value("#{val1 ? val1 : (val2 ? 'default1' : 'default2')}")`

But I keep getting:

```
`EL1008E`: property or filed 'val1' cannot be found on object of type 'org.springframeowrk.beans.factory.config.BeanExpressionContext' - maybe not public or not valid?
```

When I try other expressions, such as `${val1}` or `'${val1}'` it still does not seem to work.

What's the correct way to do nested conditions in the `@Value` annotation, or is it too complex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have adjusted the expression and written a small test to illustrate the change. In short, use `${some.prop:defaultVal}` to define a default value and use `${some.prop:}` to define an empty String as a default value. Also, use single quotes `'` in a SPEL expression to indicate the String value instead of a reference.

Play around with the `TestPropertySource` to verify the outcome. I have added a second test to show that when a default value is not present, Spring might (not always) decide to return the textual representation of the placeholder.

```java
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.test.context.TestPropertySource;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;

import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@TestPropertySource(properties = {"val1=v1", "val2=v2"})
public class SomeTest {

    @Value("#{ '${val1:}' != '' ? '${val1}' : ('${val2:}' != '' ? 'default1' : 'default2')}")
    private String testVal;

    @Value("${nonExistingValue}")
    private String nonExistingValue;

    @Test
    public void test() {
        assertThat(testVal).isEqualTo("v1");
    }

    @Test
    public void testNonExistingValue() {
        assertThat(nonExistingValue).isEqualTo("${nonExistingValue}");
    }
}
```

Although the above expression works, I would highly recommend to use [`ConfigurationProperties`](https://www.baeldung.com/configuration-properties-in-spring-boot), or a [`T expression type operator`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#expressions-types) referring to a static method. The current set up might become even less readable when the expressions becomes more complex.

Comment: Your test does not seem to work for me, since if I'm deleting `"val1=v1"` from `properties`, I'll get the following error: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'val1' in value "#{ '${val1:}' != '' ? '${val1}' : ('${val2:}' != '' ? 'default1' : 'default2')}"`

Comment: Ah, the second `'${val1}'` was simply missing `:` for empty default value. Thanks